# How to create progressbar for counting votes

Tags: jquery, css, progress-bar

I would like to create a YouTube like progressbar for counting votes

[image]

where the total votes ("likes" plus "dislikes") is the total width of the bar, and the total score ("likes" minus "dislikes") is the green part.
Now, the width of the bar must be always 100%, meaning that, it doesn't matter if total votes are 500 or 1000, that number must always be 100%, and then I need to convert that green part from a fixed number to a percentage, so, if the total votes are 1200 (100%) and the likes are 850 (green part), I need to transform those 850 likes to a percentage, I don't really know how to explain, but I hope someone can get the idea and help me.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: @Andreas try to read again, I need to convert the likes into percentage, where the total width of the bar (100%) is the sum of like and dislikes.

Comment: I've read the text but i only see a requirement and no question or a specific problem you might have. A short search for "jquery progressbar" will give you several hundred thousand of possible solutions/plugins/tutorials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you'll need to do is have a wrapper with 2 `div`s for each the likes and dislikes section contained and some javascript/jquery to control it.

**HTML**

```
<div class='progressBar'>
     <div class='likes'></div>
     <div class='dislikes'></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.progressBar {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;
    height: 10px;
}

.likes {
    background-color: #0F0;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    height: 10px;
}

.dislikes {
    background-color: #F00;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    height: 10px;
}
```

**JavaScript/jQuery**

```
var likes = 850;
var dislikes = 350;
var total = likes+dislikes;
var likePerc = (likes/total)*100;
var dislikePerc = (dislikes/total)*100;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".likes").css("width", likePerc);
    $(".dislikes").css("width", dislikePerc);
});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cLLfhhke/1/) showing how it works.

Comment: It works, but the only thing is that the bar width is always the same size, and I need it to be 100% width.

Comment: @AndresOrozco then change the code to your needs. This was intended to be an example of how to execute what your asking, not something you can just copy paste

Comment: Okay okay, I got it, I just need to add the % to the end of the resulting width. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to build this out with jQuery, I recommend only using jQuery to handle the percentage calculations and actually use HTML to create the bar, and CSS to make it responsive and pretty.

### HTML

You want to nest the 2 dynamic bars inside a parent div

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="bar up-vote"></div>
    <div class="bar down-vote"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

To make the bar responsive, you need to set the  elements to have widths as percentages.
And make sure the nested div's do not move around by setting 'box-sizing'

```
/* set all children to be defined by own border */
.parent *{
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.parent{
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.parent .bar{
    float:left;
    height:20px;
    /* give each bar a default width */
    width:50%;
}
.parent .up-vote{
    background:#35AF3F;
}
.parent .down-vote{
    background:#E24B4B;
}
```

### JS

Create your variables, statically or from whatever data is being passed in.

```
var upVote=764, 
    downVote=236, 
    totalVote,
    upPerc,
    downPerc;

// if you only know upVote and downVote, calculate totalVote
totalVote = upVote + downVote;

// calculate the percentages. Simple division, then multiply by 100
upPerc = 100* (upVote/totalVote);
downPerc = 100* (downVote/totalVote);

// if you want to round the integers to only 2 decimal places,
// use toFixed()   
upPerc = upPerc.toFixed(2);
downPerc = downPerc.toFixed(2);

// overwrite the default widths from the CSS with jQuery .css()
$('.up-vote').css({
    'width':upPerc+'%'
});
$('.down-vote').css({
    'width':downPerc+'%'
});
```

here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mlgmainstream/d38cbjwb/23/) of the working responsive bar